# Sharepoint SPGridview

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to use SPGridView in my Webpart and comes up with the assembly reference not found error.

Error   1   The type or namespace name 'SPGridView' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Could any body tell me which assembly I need to refer

Thank you
Hari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case:

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPGridView][1]
```

> in Microsoft.SharePoint.dll

Note: This is not available in Sandboxed Solutions(If you aren't developing for SharePoint 2010 ignore this.)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.SharePoint is the fellow you need.

Comment: I have already added it but it gives the error, Its kind of frustration!!1